# State params parameter after named parameter

Tags: c#

I have a method with optional parameters. Im trying to see how far i can get overloads of all possibilities.

```
public static int PrintMenu(string message = "Choose an option....", string errorMessage = "error", bool clearScreen = true, params string[] list)
```

The most important argument is the string array. Is it possible to do something like following if i want to just change one of the named parameters? :

```
PrintMenu(errorMessage: "bad input", list : "listItem 1", "listItem 2", "listItem 3");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params` are a syntactic sugar that hides the use of an array. If you want to name it explicitly, you need to instantiate the array.

```cs
PrintMenu(errorMessage: "bad input", list: new[] { "listItem 1", "listItem 2", "listItem 3" });
```

That said, I would advise against over-using named parameters and `params`. Often it is a sign of a code smell with a method that takes too many parameters and/or performs too many tasks. It also makes it harder to use or read afterwards.

That's why I prefer to explicitly declare overloads and only use optional parameters for obvious flags (usually boolean) while limiting it to at most two such arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  Do it like this

```
PrintMenu(errorMessage: "Bad input", list: new string[] { "list item 1", "list item 2"});
```